# Is there a way to add a class/id to a selector?

Tags: html, css, selector

Let's say I have some HTML that looks like this:

```
<div id="non-adjustable">
    <a id="adjustable-a" href="example.html">
        <div id="adjustable-div">Button</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Then I have a stylesheet with some fantastic animations that I want to add to the `#non-adjustable` div.

**Limitations/Requirements:**

1. I **cannot** edit the HTML of the `#non-adjustable` div so I cannot add a class to that div.
2. I **can** edit the HTML under the `#non-adjustable` div (`#adjustable-a` and `#adjustable-div`).
3. I **can** edit the CSS but I cannot take the styling from the animation stylesheet (I can only use the classes inside the stylesheet).

Basically, if this was a thing, I'd want to be able to do this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
      #non-adjustable(.fantastic-animation) {
           /*Other Declarations*/
      }
 </style>
```

But that either doesn't work, or I did it incorrectly. Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Since the animation classes are predefined, I'm assuming there are some restrictions about which elements `.fantastic-animation` can be applied to. Which elements is `.fantastic-animation` supposed to be applied to inside `#non-adjustable`?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to use CSS to add a HTML class. That's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the :before and :after pseudo elements and style them to fit your needs.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

This is what most font libraries do... They create pseudo elements in the stylesheet and set the background image, the alignment, etc.